# R .call argument in stop function

Tags: r

What is the use of `.call` argument in `stop` function?

The help page (`stop`) explains:

> call. logical, indicating if the call should become part of the error message.

Could some one explain the `.call` argument with an intuitive example?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just try it yourself:

```
f = function () stop('foo')

g = function () stop('bar', call. = FALSE)

f() # Error in f(): foo
g() # Error: bar
```

… and compare the output. That’s the only difference.

The use of the argument is when you want to hide irrelevant detail from the end user that would otherwise drown out the actual error message or be actively misleading.

For instance, [I have a package](https://github.com/klmr/modules) which contains the following functions<sup>1</sup>:

```
#' @export
import = function (module, ...) {
    # … some code here …
    module_path = find_module(module)
    # … more code here …
}

find_module = function (module) {
    # … some code here …
    if (no_module_found)
        stop('Unable to load module ', module, '.', call. = FALSE)
}
```

Now, as you can see the function `import` is exported from the package, but the function `find_module` isn’t. Consequently the user doesn’t know about this function, and *should not know* about it: it’s an irrelevant implementation detail. If I hadn’t specified `call. = FALSE` in the `stop` above, then the error message would have contained a reference to this hidden function, which would just have confused the user of the package.

---

<sup>1</sup> That’s a small lie, the code is now different; but an earlier version of the package actually *did* contain this code.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but what is the use of ignoring the function name in the error message?

Comment: @Sathish `f <- function(...){stop("foo")}; f(asdlfjaslkdjfalksdjflkajsd,asdfaskdfklajsdljkf, asdlkfjaksdjfklajsdlfkasd, asldkfjaksjdflkajsdlfkjsadklfj, asdfkljaskdjflkjasd=3, askldjfajsdlkfjlksajdf =3, aljsdfkjaskdjf =34)` Hmmm... maybe we don't want to print the full call always...

Comment: @Dason Thanks for the answer. I think, you explained part of the answer to the question. Is it possible to edit Konrad 's answer to make it a complete one?

Comment: @Sathish Apologies, I misunderstood the question. I’ve now added an example to the answer. Dason’s example is also good.